# can we partition by two fields in dbt

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cloud, dbt

here is my scenario i have a table where i am loading the yearly data with country_id (integer).
so i want to partition it by country_id then year.
i am using insert_overwrite strategy.

> ```
> sample code:
> {{ config(materialized='incremental',incremental_strategy="insert_overwrite",cluster_by = ["country_id"],partition_by={"field": "year","data_type": "int64","range": {"start": 2000,"end": 3000,"interval": 1}}) }}
> ```

I am planning to implement append stratergy and partition column will be country_id and year.
if you have suggestion it will be appreciated.

Comment: There is only one partition column allowed and a maximum of 4000 partitions. Clustering by country is a possibility, but does not save much. Depending on the ETL, you could add a colum `TEMP` before uploading to BigQuery. This column is the year concated the country, and by that column the table is partition.

Comment: i am doing the transformation through DBT , i think the DBT wont allow string columns for partitioning correct me if i am wrong